# Check whether row in table exists with provided primary ID of row

Tags: hibernate

Is there any convenient and fast method in Hibernate with which I can check the existence of a row in database table by providing the primary Id of that row.

I don't want to pull the object because some other tables are linked with it and loading that record object results in pretty heavy query which I don't want for simple boolean check. So looking for a simple and fast way to check whether row with given Id exists or not

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you have to hit the database to do what you have in mind. If you have turned on caching, Hibernate might avoid hitting the database if the object you are looking for is present in the cache. But that is something you can't be sure about. It is possible that the table has that row and it is not yet fetched to the cache. So it kind of becomes necessary to hit the database.

Once you are hitting the database, the next best thing you can do is to not fetch the entire object and all its related objects and so on. You can do this in many ways - (1) create a minimal entity with only the required columns - in this case, the id column might be all you need to fetch. (2) fire a query which only fetches the columns you need.

Comment: What if I use Projections.rowCount() to get only count?

Comment: That will work too. Basically, the point is, you can't avoid a database hit. And look for the least invasive way to hit the database. You could check the difference in times for a couple of methods.